# How to create custom Django URL filter

Tags: django, url, filter

I have set up a django project and i use the viewsets.ModelViewSet.
I need to use some custom filters from my react project through url that  calls to the api, something like
.../model/username="Test"/
where the username is the foreignKey in my model.
I deploy my backend in Heroku.
Thank you

I tried using different kind of ready packages, but they did not work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.